# Why I conda activate env with python3.7, but python version still is python3.5?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I installed Miniconda3 on Ubuntu 16, and used the command

```bash
conda create -n py37 python=3.7
```

to create an env, and use command `conda activate py37` to activate the env. But when I use command `python --version` to check my Python version, it show the version of Python is 3.5.2. So I try to create another env with Python 2.7, but after I activate this env, the version of Python is still 3.5.2.

#### Debugging

When I type `type python`, it shows `python` is aliased to `'/usr/bin/python3.5.2'`. Then by using the command to edit the `.bashrc` file, I found that there is a line of statement

```bash
alias python='/usr/bin/python3.5.2'
```

so I tried to change to

```bash
alias python='/home/vagrant/miniconda3/envs/django-judge/bin/python'
```

where the Python version of the env is 3.7. Then when I type `type python` again, it returns that python is aliased to `'/home/vagrant/miniconda3/envs/django-judge/bin/python'`. But now, under all envs, the Python version has become Python 3.7.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the alias altogether: it is not compatible with Conda to alias `python`.